# Cpp self copy access denied

Tags: c++, copy, replication

So i am trying to create a self replicating .exe in c++ using `code::blocks`. I have written the code and on my local machine it works flawlessly. After loading it on a Windows 7 Virtual machine and 2 other PCs, i realized it does not work. It comes up with the error

"Can not copy file, access denied"

My PC probably has different permissions set i am assuming which is why it works on mine and not others. Here is the section of code:

```
ifstream check( "C:\\newfile.exe" );

if( !check.is_open() )
{
    char bufferf[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, bufferf, MAX_PATH );
    std::stringstream str;

    str << "copy " << bufferf << " C:\\newfile.exe";
    system( str.str().c_str() );
    system( "start c:\\newfile.exe" );
    cout << __argv[0] << endl;
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;

}
```

Remember i am very new to c++, long time java, php and c# developer but i figured it is time to learn a lower level language. If you have any suggestions on making this a more efficient function then please let me know.show any code you can since im not 100% familiar with all the libraries yet. long story short i want to copy the current exe to the cdrive, run that copied file and close the original. here is another way i tried

```
ifstream check( "C:\\newFile.exe" );

if( !check.is_open() )
{
    char bufferf[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, bufferf, MAX_PATH );

    char * original_file = bufferf;
    char * new_file = ( char * )"c:\\newFile.exe";
    ( void ) CopyFile( ( LPCTSTR )original_file, ( LPCTSTR )new_file, FALSE );
    system( "start c:\\newFile.exe" );
    cout << __argv[0];
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Still no success. but both work flawlessly on my development machine (from what i can see) i heard people say you can not copy running exe files in windows but that is not true, i feel it is a permissions issue but i may be wrong.

Any tips on self replication are welcome, i'm open to new methods.

Comment: To be honest that question looks suspicious and your statement of being a long time java and c# developer is questionable. Normally you would want to have some sort of archive which gets extracted and then executes one of the containing files but combining this in one program is something which doesn't sound very common and I can't see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: i have been a professional web application engineer for 15 years, over 15 different languages and this is the first question i have ever asked online,also why does it seem suspicious? It is being written for a 3rd party apache controller to keep logs and timing on certain functions on the server. i want it as a standalone exe, as uncommon as it sounds, it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please know that, Windows Vista and Windows 7 have UAC enabled which doesn't allow you to "write" to certain folders. You might have to run the program in Administrator mode or disable UAC altogether for your program to copy/create file from one location to the protected special folder.

To request the user to allow a program to be run in administrative mode, you must define and link a manifest file to your application:  This tells you how to do it.

Comment: yes that is what i thought, on my local machine i disabled UAC but on xp this is doing the same thing which as far as i understand does not have UAC enabled. i have a work around but i like to figure things out so do you have any ways that i can avoid the uac in windows? after running it as an administrator it worked like a charm. any way to over ride this? or even prompt the user?

Comment: define and link your own manifest file. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66259/Requesting-Admin-Approval-at-Application-Start check this on HOW TO DO IT.

Comment: @evanhayes, I hope it helped. If so, selecting the answer as "correct" is the way to thank me :-)

Comment: PERFECT i will try generating it from within the exe and all should work, thank you very much!